# Accessing forwarded VM ports from other computers on local network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, port-forwarding, localhost

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 machine, running Debian in VirtualBox. I have an Apache server on the Debian VM, with a web site on port 80. `localhost:80` on the VM works for accessing the site. I have guest port 80 forwarded to host port 8000 in VirtualBox; `localhost:8000` accesses the website on Windows.

Now here's my issue: I want to connect to the website from another computer on my local network. I've gone into Windows Firewall and allowed both inbound and outbound connections on port 8000. But `nmap` on the second computer tells me that port 8000 is not open, and therefore it can't access the website in a browser, via `local-ip-address:8000`.

Any ideas on what to try from here? Is there other firewall software preinstalled with Windows 8.1? I used an install disc, so no OEM bloatware, and I haven't installed any other security software (just using Defender for antivirus).

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing virtualbox completely through windows firewall on all networks, public and private, and see what happens.

Comment: VirtualBox already had a few rules in Windows Firewall. After reading this answer I changed them to be as permissive as possible, and it still doesn't work.